# Getting Informatica Session log through Shell Scripting

Tags: unix, scripting, informatica

Is there a way to capture information logs ( session or workflow ) and grep only ERROR or FAIL messages and send to email distro 
using mailx or sendmail option.

I have around 200 sessions running on daily basis and this script has to run every day , and capture only error information .

Thanks

Comment: Most likely. Post some sample data, expected output and let's see.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple, so long as you configure the session to write backwards compatible logfiles then it'll lose all the encoded junk and you can grep for $ERROR or $FAIL